# Evaluating a definite integral using substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to evaluate the definite integral: $$\int_0^2 (e^{4x} - 4x)^4(e^{4x} - 1)dx$$

I am having trouble evaluating this because I am not sure what to put as $u$.

I was thinking about putting $u=4x$ so that I could get $(1/4)du=dx$.

However now I am stuck.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $u = e^{4x} - 4x$ then $du = (4e^{4x} - 4)\,dx = 4(e^{4x} - 1) dx$ then we have

$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{e^8 - 8} u^4 du$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yea I think so. I would end up doing F(b)-F(a) right?

Comment: Yes, it's a simple polynomial integral.

Comment: May I ask how did you get e^8-8?

Comment: @AaronMaroja: I believe you missed the exponent of $4x$ instead of just $x$.

Comment: With definite integrals you need to be careful with the integration limits. Place $x = 0$ and $x = 2$ in $u = e^{4x} - 4x$, to see why.

Comment: @calculusbyparts Thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=e^{4x}-4x$, then $du=4(e^{4x}-1)\,dx$.